# Finding  really big power of a number

Tags: java, math

I am creating a small game for students, and in a place, it has to display the value of 2<sup>7830457</sup>+1

I can call BigInteger's pow() method if the number is not this much big. Since the number is very big, that method is useless. How can I find the HUGE power of this kind of numbers? Please help!

Comment: Why don't you just display it in that exponential form? That number wouldn't fit on a computer screen.

Comment: If you just display two million random digits, noone will notice anything wrong with it---or even care if they knew the number was off. What educational value lies in the **precise** sequence of two million digits?

Comment: Only the first few numbers will be displayed. Complete numbers will be written to a file. At least, that's what I am suggesting to do. 

And no, the answer must be correct. There is a guru out there waiting for the exact answer.

Comment: Does this have anything to do with [Project Euler](https://projecteuler.net/problem=97)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know why you think `BigInteger` isn't up to this:

```
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        BigInteger big = BigInteger.valueOf(2)
            .pow(7830457)
            .add(BigInteger.ONE);
        System.out.println(big);
    }
}
```

It takes a little while (particularly the string conversion at the end), but it's perfectly reasonable.

As Peter noted, shifting `ONE` left 7830457 is much neater, mind you. I'd argue it's a bit less clear - and of course it doesn't help in the string conversion part.

EDIT: Almost all of the time is spent in the string conversion. It finished in the end on my box though. I can't see the *start* of it any more, but it ends with...

```
08570502260645006898157834607641626568029302766491883299164453304032280181734737
79366998940913082443120328458954436211937775477966920836932628607888755839700303
873
```

Comment: Can't use it. It will take years to give the result.

Comment: How many minutes did it take in your machine? Did you run it in an IDE? What is your RAM? Please answer :)

Comment: @Sepala: The version which *didn't* print out the string finished quickly. The version which converts it to a string is still going, admittedly - but I doubt that it'll take years :) My machine has 8GB of memory, but the JVM is only using about 150MB at the moment. (And no, it's running on the command line.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I guess my machine will be 4 times slower than yours then. I am running it now. Will let you know

Comment: @Sepala: Why would you guess your machine would be 4 times slower? If nothing's *using* the extra memory, it won't make a difference. It's still going, admittedly... but it's all in the string conversion.

Comment: Because it is still running, the NON-PRINT version is still running here o.O

Comment: That is done. How many mins did it take to run the version with print?

Comment: @Sepala: About 10 minutes, judging by the timing of the comments. It's finished - see my edit for the end of the number. (It's filled my console buffer, so I can't see the start...)

Comment: Is it really the conversion to String, or the console output that takes most time? How long does it run when you redirect the output to a file?

Comment: @DanielFischer: Console output doesn't take that long, at least relative to the amount spent for the conversion.

Comment: @DanielFischer By far the conversion. AFAIK, Java 7 still uses an `O(n^2)` algorithm for conversions. So I'm quite surprised that it managed to finish at all for something that's 2 million digits long.

Comment: @tskuzzy I'm just surprised because `writeFile "BigPow.txt" $ show (2^27830457 + 1) ++ "\n"` (Haskell) takes only 3.8 seconds from ghci. Seems BigInteger's `toString()` isn't particularly fast.

Comment: hahahah! Now they are asking me to multiply the answer with 2000!!!!! I just started hating this........

Answer (score 8):

Well in binary it's just `10000...01` with 7830456 zeros.

In decimal, there will be approximately two million digits, which is about 2 megabytes of storage. This is well within the feasibility of `BigInteger` with a default heap size.

In practice, it even uses [exponentiation by squaring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) to compute it quickly (though not guaranteed by the specifications). However the conversion to a `String` will take some time since it's a linear time operation.

```
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class BigPow {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BigInteger result = (new BigInteger("2")).pow(27830457).add(BigInteger.ONE);
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

Here's a version which will print out the digits slowly:

```
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class BigPow {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BigInteger result = (new BigInteger("2")).pow(27830457).add(BigInteger.ONE);
        BigInteger powten = BigInteger.TEN.pow(2357202);

        while(powten.compareTo(BigInteger.TEN) > 0) {
            BigInteger digit = result.divide(powten).mod(BigInteger.TEN);
            System.out.print(digit);
            powten = powten.divide(BigInteger.TEN);
        }
    }
}
```

The first digits are:

> 27337386390628313557307248857732033008168556429738078791761607160549944954510637855005417718646965163546351365984857761796847950377880836291434244529029919271706271982523405687134334692691344477538489450971091437463160940371624647030064741968436401566711255284353690448270545402444641547030399228243743315193608710148721648879085592699913299745785392609301774185427367430782834290629265859073814466687714408436025809860462926275610087354595992436000187216152954542774991509992374985538879880897902639600451627914923043483436514419544413306391278529303650112773297502090619459167888563274071587848623085880067091968911236296732119252937497152769541579516150659424997041968213122450568364121976474269097910635641227922923398092242409755554115985855831015459204780391470591543281267373716556272259386683864538263922398723602210173800151405332100275913619559563575829498369806957031526077258236305186254269056811134135133350936924294101345294335698866339561918857584229744277901180792029180156485000086528174400878657004645726892816943589969701053158760210512171516969813345080894134663207988962182426459128577282934948790911691329475034324656384238413230485050607666988301932660490870167246016897007835866691705399794247746213819662270451531049826029606671683482160663572103374

Confirmed by [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2%5E7830457%2b1).

Comment: OK. Do you mind giving an example please? I didn't understand actually

Comment: damn! What kind of web resource is that!!! How on earth it is that much fast????????????????????

Comment: @Sepala That's the power of advanced algorithms. Java uses `O(n^2)` algorithms for multiplication and conversions. WolframAlpha uses GMP which has an `O(n*log(n))` for multiplication and `O(n*log(n)^2)` for conversions.

Comment: awesome! I don't know what GMP is. Is that is a programming language? When I google it it showing pharmacies, medicine and "Good Manufacture" results. If it is a language, I am glad to learn it! Please give me some more info!

Comment: +1 for exponantion by squaring, it solved my problem

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to calculate this with BigInteger.

```
 System.out.println(BigInteger.ONE.shiftLeft(7830457).add(BigInteger.ONE));
```

Comment: In this case, with a shift and an or. `BigInteger.ONE.shift(7830457).add(BigInteger.ONE)` or something

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
BigInteger mant = new BigInteger("2");
BigInteger result = mant.pow(7830457).add(BigInteger.ONE);
```